# Why isn't amplitude modulation used more often in magnetic resonance technologies?

Tags: electromagnetism, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

Optically pumped magnetometers utilize a visible light carrier wave which is amplitude modulated down to a Larmor frequency of ~1000 Hz. This is in contrast to the vast majority of magnetic resonance implementations where the carrier frequency is equal to the Larmor frequency.

Why are there not more technologies that exploit amplitude modulation at the Larmor frequency?

This seems like it would be an easy way to excite spins over a broad frequency range without retuning the resonator.

Amplitude modulation seems to satisfy the Bloch equations and excite spins just fine, so why not more widespread use?

Answer (score 0):

Because AM needs a strong carrier and whose modulation rate is much less than the carrier frequency. In NMR, as mentioned in the answer of @AadhavVenkatesan, the "carrier" is actually a constant bias field. So the closest to AM one can have with that kind of background is a pulsed or On/OFF keying type modulation, and this is in fact what is used.

Comment: That's correct but optically pumped magnetometers utilize visible light amplitude modulated down to a Larmor frequency on the order of ~1000 hertz. This is fundamentally different from the rest of magnetic resonance technologies where the carrier is tuned to Larmor frequency.